# Accessing integers from an object of class Object

Tags: java, arrays, object, int

In the code below an integer array is assigned to an object. If that's possible, why can't i access them  through obj? The code compiles, but i get a ClassCastException, I have tried casting the object to String, i get the same error

```
public class test
{ public static void main(String ab[])
  { 
   Object obj = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   Integer[] i = (Integer[]) obj;
   for( Integer c : i)    
   System.out.println(c);       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int[]` is not the same as an `Integer[]`.

You create an `int[]`:

```
Object obj = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

But then you attempt to cast it back to an `Integer[]`, which you cannot do, because it is an `int[]`. `int[]` and `Integer[]` are both `Object`, but you cannot cast between the two like that, for the same reason that, e.g., this does not work:

```
Object obj = new String("");
File f = (File)obj; // obj is a String, will throw ClassCastException
```

Instead, either create an `Integer[]` to begin with:

```
Object obj = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
Integer[] i = (Integer[]) obj;
```

Or use an `int[]`:

```
Object obj = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int[] i = (int[]) obj;
```

The same is true of your attempt to cast an `int[]` to a `String`. You can't convert things just by casting them around in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are trying to cast an object of type int[] to an object of type Integer[], that is not possible, although an Integer class can hold int types and in later versions of java you can even assign an int to an Integer like this:

```
Integer a = 2;
```

they are different.

If you are using java 5 or above you can do something like this:

```
public class test
{ public static void main(String ab[])
  { 
   Object obj = new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
   Integer[] i = (Integer[]) obj;
   for( Integer c : i)    
   System.out.println(c);       
  }
}
```